# Difference between akamai and cloudflare

Tags: cloud, cdn, scalability, price

I want to confirm pricing plan, Users, Uptime and response time between these two CDNs. I want to confirm which is better for as video streaming CDN.

Akamai has more experience with the enterprise market, with 5000 enterprise customers. CloudFlare's pricing plan is focused on SMBs which typically have lower requirements for scale, performance, availability and security.

I need your good experience feature wise.

Comment: This is a broad topic. But while doing your research, I recommend considering *where* in the world you are planning to deliver content to. Some CDNs have cool features but may not have very good global coverage. Cheers!